# Hide url on url_launch plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

Need to hide URL launched by using url_launcher. I can use inAppwebview, etc. but some of the feature is not working on that. is there any way I can open Chrome or a browser engine with a hiding URL?

```
final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
      await launchUrl(
        uri,
        mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
      );
    } else {
      // can't launch url
    }
```

I have done POC but my Url is visible on that POC.

Comment: You can use Env for hide url, but i think can't hide url in browser.

Comment: 1. you can launch url in FLutter_webview
2.  You can buy a domain name and Mask it, so that real url gets hidden.

Comment: @RamGupta on point 1 some of the functionality is not working. on point 2, I have a dynamic query parameter link with imp data on that.